# Yolo/SSD: How are features localized?

Tags: machine-learning, object-detection

I want to fully understand how Yolo or SSD does work for object detection.

Here is what I understand:

- in a simple CNN for image recognition, features are extracted, flattend and used for a classification
- yolo devides the image into a grid. For each grid, some values like class probabilities and the bounding box parameters are calculated.
- SSD not only uses one grid , but a combination of different sizes to better detect objects at any size.

What I don't understand:

- in yolo and ssd, there is a classification per grid cell? How do we know, which features are in that specific cell?
- are features extracted per grid cell or per bounding box or non of both?
- how does ssd combine results from different grids?

Thank you!